# SQL convert 2d array into 1d array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

is there a way to convert a 2d array into a 1d array with sql? see picture and example below.

basically in the collapse column (see attached screenshot), instead of having array(array(int)), i'd need array(int) - so instead of [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], i'd need [0,0,0,0,0,0]

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh postgres

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by using *flatten* function